# Measurement protocol to GA4 through chrome extension does not show engaged sessions count

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I am using measurement protocol to send data to my GA4 property from my chrome extension as there is no support for chrome extension in gtag.js yet. The problem I am facing is though I am sending session_id i.e (ga_session_id) and also sending  engagement_time_msec along with timestamp_micros but I am unable to see engaged sessions in engagement overview report. User stickiness graph and user activity over time these sections are showing charts but engaged sessions are not getting automatically calculated by GA4 dashboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o5Vk.png)

after trying out all the parameters related to session through measurement protocol it still does not show any changes in engagement overview

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?